# Tune a Regex to match a string *only* at the beginning of a message

Tags: python, regex, python-2.x

I have the following code which matches `rdar://problem` (one or more) in the commit_msg, I only want to match it at the beginning of the message, please note that it could be more than one rdar at the beginning of the message, how can I change the regex to do that?

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
commit_msg = """
<rdar://problem/19391231> This is the subject line1
<rdar://problem/11121314> This is the subject line2
[Problem]
The Problem description

[Solution]
This is the Solutions section

[Recommended Tests]
This is the Recommended Tests <rdar://problem/12345678> Text

Change-Id: Ibbafa780adb2502d470f12d0280ddb0049c727c4
Reviewed-on: https://tech-gerrit.sd.company.com/17954
Tested-by: Username1 <username1@company.com>
Build-watchOS: service account <serviceaccount@company.com>
Reviewed-by: username2 <username2@company.com>
"""
m = re.findall("(?!.*(?:Revert|revert))[\S]*(?:rdar:\/\/problem\/)(\d{8,8})", commit_msg)

print m
```

CURRENT OUTPUT:-

```
['19391231', '11121314', '12345678']
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT:-

```
['19391231', '11121314']
```

Comment: That message starts with a newline and a `<`, not with `rdar`. What can be ignored for counting as "starting" with `rdar://...`? What would a commit message that starts with more than one such URNs look like, so it can be distinguished from a message that has a "non-starting" `rdar` URN?

Comment: @ShadowRanger - It doesnt need to have `<` at the start ,need to match all `rdar://...` at the start,I updated my question aswell for multiple `rdar`

Comment: Is it guaranteed to have the section header `[Problem]` as the first thing after the "start" area? Or even just a guarantee the a line beginning with `[` is definitely after the stuff you want to match? Because a much easier solution than trying to regex the whole thing is to find a good split delimiter that cuts off the part you don't care about, so the regex can operate solely on text that contains the matches you care about, without complicated exclusion criteria.

Comment: @ShadowRanger - It is guaranteed that a line beginning with `[` will occur after the stuff we want to match

Comment: So would a preliminary `re.split` on the pattern `r'^\['` (with `re.MULTILINE` so it will recognize `^` as matching at the beginning of lines within the string) or even just a call to `str`'s `partition` method (`fullstr.partition('\n[')[0]`), keeping only the first element, allow you to write a simpler (human readable/understandable) pattern to check for the URN format you want?

Comment: @ShadowRanger - sounds worth a try...if you be exactly specific with the regex, I would be able to share info if that's working or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Going off your conversation with @ShadowRanger below, how about this?

```
import re
commit_msg = """
<rdar://problem/19391231> This is the subject line1
<rdar://problem/11121314> This is the subject line2
[Problem]
The Problem description

[Solution]
This is the Solutions section

[Recommended Tests]
This is the Recommended Tests <rdar://problem/12345678> Text

Change-Id: Ibbafa780adb2502d470f12d0280ddb0049c727c4
Reviewed-on: https://tech-gerrit.sd.company.com/17954
Tested-by: Username1 <username1@company.com>
Build-watchOS: service account <serviceaccount@company.com>
Reviewed-by: username2 <username2@company.com>
"""
m = re.findall("(?!.*(?:Revert|revert))[\S]*(?:rdar:\/\/problem\/)(\d{8,8})", commit_msg.split('[')[0])

print m
```